# How to parse the media:group tag in the rss feed in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsxmlparser, rss-reader

I tried to parse the "media:group" tag manually or via FeedKit swift. But getting the nil response for this. Please let me know how to parse this tag.

This is url of rss feed http://www.rollingstone.com/music/rss and format is like this

```
<media:group>
<media:content url="http://img.wennermedia.com/featured/rs-jb-5db24d0d-72d6-4f17-b7b8-0aa192b13dc3.jpg"/>
<media:content url="http://img.wennermedia.com/article-leads-vertical/rs-jb-5db24d0d-72d6-4f17-b7b8-0aa192b13dc3.jpg"/>
<media:thumbnail url="http://img.wennermedia.com/reading-list/rs-jb-5db24d0d-72d6-4f17-b7b8-0aa192b13dc3.jpg"/>
</media:group>
```

Answer (score 0):

`media` is namespace in xml language, tag name will be `group`.
If it's important to know tag namespace, then you should enable `shouldProcessNamespaces` and `shouldReportNamespacePrefixes` in `NSXMLParser`.

Comment: Thanks #Cy, could you please give me a link or reference for it.

Comment: @GopalDevra https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsxmlparser/1418380-shouldprocessnamespaces?language=objc and https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsxmlparser/1410809-shouldreportnamespaceprefixes?language=objc

Comment: Thank u #Cy, I am testing this reference and let you know, is it working or not.